# this parent jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, parent

**jQuery**

```
$(".drop-down h3").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent(".drop-down").find($("ul")).stop().slideToggle();
  $(this).parent(".drop-down").find($(".divider-aside")).stop().toggle("slow");
  $(this).parent(".drop-down").find($(".arrow")).stop().toggleClass("rotate1 rotate2");
});
```

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="categories">
  <div class="drop-down">
    <h3>Categories</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="divider-aside"></div>
  <ul>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>12323</li>
    <li>1231</li>
    <li>523</li>
    <li>31</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to hide everything in `.drop-down` class excluding `<h3>` by clicking on `<h3>`. In this case only `.arrow` toggleClass works.

Comment: Instead of `parent()`, use `.closest()`

Comment: The only thing in the `.drop-down` class is the h3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `closest`  instead of `parent`

```
$(this).closest("#categories")
```

parent will only go back 1 level , i.e, the immediate parent. But you gotta get the container that encloses all the 3 elements

So   `$(this).parent(".drop-down")`

supposed to be either

```
$(this).parent().parent()   // this will break if there is an extra
                            // parent container gets added
```

**or**

```
$(this).closest("#categories") // This will work even if the no of
                               // parent container keep chaning
```

Comment: i'll stay with - $(this).parent().parent(), Thanks so much :) i will accept this answer

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(this).closest("#categories")`, not `$(this).closest(".categories")` as @user2587741 is using `<div id="categories">` in the example?

Comment: @dgurtner You are right. Must have overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

if you need toggle them all but the .drop-down .siblings is just what you need

```
$("div.drop-down > h3").click(function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.parent().siblings().toggle();
});
```